# Как загнать не простую строку в массив

Tags: c#

Есть строка, которая не совсем простая

```
"    Книги       Учебная литература       Дошкольникам       Общая подготовка к школе     "
```

Как мне из этого сделать массив? Первое слово начинается после четырех пробелов, потом остальные после 7.
Должно получиться так

```
array[0] = "Книги"
array[1] = "Учебная литература"
и тд
```

причем длина у строки может быть разная. Для этих целей подойдет массив?

Comment: `str.Trim().Split(new string[] {"       "}, StringSplitOptions.None);` - между кавычками 7 пробелов

Comment: Тоже не помогло.

Comment: Помогло, это Вы неправильно код скопировали :)

Comment: Может у вас колонки разделены по позициям? Очень на это похоже.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string str = "    Книги       Учебная литература       Дошкольникам       Общая подготовка к школе     ";
string[] items = str.Trim().Split(new string[] {"       "}, StringSplitOptions.None); // между кавычками 7 пробелов
```

Comment: Не получается. Каждое слово заганяется в отдельную ячейку массива и плюс все пробелы

Comment: @shatoidil // между кавычками 7 пробелов

Comment: Все сработало!  Отлично

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте например так:

```
string str = "    Книги       Учебная литература       Дошкольникам       Общая подготовка к школе     ";
var arr = str.Split(new[] {"  "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(x => x.Trim()).ToArray();
```

Comment: `array[1] = "Учебная литература"`

Comment: Да он делит каждое слово

Comment: @shatoidil поправил, посмотрите

Comment: @DreamChild Да так же каждое слово попадает в отдельную ячейку массива а надо что бы array[1] = "Учебная литература" было так . То есть пусть он игнорит единичный пробел, и убирает робелы больше одного

Comment: @shatoidil вы проверьте. Нормально работает. Там разбиение на строки происходит не по одному, а по двум пробелам